# Using ES6 Module Libraries in Angular Applications and Unexpected token 'export' Error

Tags: javascript, angular, module, es6-modules

I have a JavaScript library I'm trying use within an Angular application. It is written with ES6 syntax and exports itself as a module.

```
export { Q as Library };
```

Imported into `Angular.json` as you do:

```
architect: {
build: {
options: {
   "scripts": [
      "src/assets/libs/library.min.js"
   ]
```

Angular loads the script but with a module syntax error.

```
scripts.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Here is my `tsconfig`

```
compilerOptions
  "target": "es2020",
  "module": "es2020",
  "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
  ]
```

How can I properly import this module into the application?

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can import directly into your component instead of adding to the script file;

See this sample demo in [This Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-keller-nul6g?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

In this example I have made a file **q.js** with the contents

```js
const Q = {
  qualityLog: (properties) => {
    Object.entries(properties).forEach(([key, element]) => {
      console.log("|============================")
      console.log("|------  >|",key)
      console.log("|------  =|",element)
      console.log("|============================")
    });
  }
}

export {Q as Library};
```

In my component I am using it like below

```
import { Library } from 'path/to/q';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  ngOnInit () {
    Library.qualityLog({title: this.title})
  }
}
```

In the console we see [image: Console Log]

The import is correctly working

Comment: That seems to work when importing into a component. You mentioned importing into a module though? How can that work so all its deps can use the lib?